# param is missing or the value is empty: sale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

This issue happens when I create a Sale someone know why? I believe the params in sales_controller are nil, I always create things from new view with scaffold or without it but this once that I'm going to create from other view so I don't know how to resolve this error. Please help me brothers.

Error:

> ActionController::ParameterMissing in SalesController#create
>   param is missing or the value is empty: sale
>
> Rails.root: C:/Users/osmarvirux/Downloads/store_geeks
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>      app/controllers/sales_controller.rb:16:in 'sale_params'
>      app/controllers/sales_controller.rb:3:in 'create' 
>      Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"D6nFaEak+A8W+ykkQuk7wnK0vqbfuIxIGJDT0mQ0FODTyBAiy8F39491tfYJi9yJ5tzwFNxa6SfqfMuzZt3YVA=="}

## sales_controller.rb

```
 class SalesController < ApplicationController
        def create
          sale = Sale.create(sale_params)     
          respond_to do |format|
            if sale.save
              format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Datos guardados exitosamente.' }          
            else
              format.html { redirect_to root_path, alert: 'Hubo un error, comunicate con nosotros a cualquier numero telefonico' }
            end
          end      
        end

        private

        def sale_params
          params.require(:sale).permit(:country, :state, :city, :street, :colony, :number, :postal_code)
        end    
    end
```

## payment_succeed.haml

```
 .col-md-10.center-block.no-float.top-space.bottom
     %articule.card.large-padding

      %section.big-top-space
       %h2 Resumen de tu pedido
       .table-responsive
        %table.table.table-striped.table-hover.medium#table_shopping_cart
         %thead
          %td.success Product
          %td.success Costo   
         %tbody
          -@shopping_cart.in_shopping_carts.each do |i_sh|
           -product = i_sh.product
           %tr{id: "#{product.id}"}
            %td= product.name
            %td= "#{product.pricing / 100} USD"
           .col-lg-12
            %a.btn.btn-link.bold.medium.capitalize{"role" => 'button', "data-toggle" => 'collapse', "href": "#payment_succeed", "aria-expanded" => 'false', "aria-controls" => "payment_succeed"}
             Agregar informacion               
            .collapse#payment_succeed
             .well.inline-block.no-margin.no-padding
              .form-group   
               =form_tag "/ok", method: :post, class: "no-margin no-padding" do
                =text_field_tag :key_sale,nil, class:"form-control floating-label", placeholder: "Key"
                =text_field_tag :country,nil, class:"form-control floating-label", placeholder: "Pais"
                =text_field_tag :state,nil, class:"form-control floating-label", placeholder: "Estado"
                =text_field_tag :city,nil, class:"form-control floating-label", placeholder: "Ciudad"
                =text_field_tag :street,nil, class:"form-control floating-label", placeholder: "Calle"
                =text_field_tag :colony,nil, class:"form-control floating-label", placeholder: "Colonia"
                =number_field_tag :number,nil, class:"form-control floating-label", placeholder: "Numero"
                =number_field_tag :postal_code,nil, class:"form-control floating-label", placeholder: "Numero postal"
                =content_tag :button, type: :submit, class:"btn btn-primary bold" do
                 Aceptar
```

## route

```
post "/ok", to: "sales#create"
```

Comment: The error message will give you important information on how to track down the problem. Please edit your question to include the error message from the Rails log.

Comment: try using `form_for` instead of `form_tag`

Comment: i tried with form_for but didn't work brother :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strong params are looking for the following format, with `sale` as the root key:

```
{ "utf8"=>"✓", "sale" => {"country"=> "USA"} }
```

Based on your log, there aren't any params coming through the `POST`. Try putting a value into one of the inputs and committing the `POST` again to see if a param comes through. If it doesn't, try using [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) to step through this issue with your form setup.

Also, you are declaring that you expect `sale` to be the root key. You could also loosen this restriction by changing the `sale_params` method to be:

```
def sale_params
  params.permit(:country, :state, :city, :street, :colony, :number, :postal_code)
end
```

which would allow your params to drop the root key:

```
{ "utf8"=>"✓", "country"=> "USA" }
```

Comment: thanks Sr. works with def sale_params
  params.permit(:country, :state, :city, :street, :colony, :number, :postal_code)
end
BUT the parameter's are nil do you know why?

Comment: I can't tell from the code posted - are they nil even after you've submitted the form with values within the inputs? That would suggest that there's an issue with your form setup. It would help to see the HTML that was generated for the form

Comment: all works fine Sr. i restarted the server the soluciotion was change params.permit(:country, :state, :city, :street, :colony, :number, :postal_code)  Can you explain me why ? o.O it suppose that require(:sale) <--- is the model i dont undertand why i have to delete it can you tell me? thanks a lot

Comment: I think I explained the reason for this in the answer. If this helped, would you mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby on Rails, we can pass the strong parameter and without passing strong params.

But i suggest always use strong parameter because "assume unsafe until proven otherwise"

when your application assigns the data from a user input to multiple objects, variables, of database fields at once. Updating the object’s properties allows an attacker to modify or overwrite the existing data.

Strong Parameter:

```
 def user_params
      params.require(:sales).permit(:country)
 end
```

{ "utf8"=>"✓", "sale" => {"country"=> "USA"} }

Without Storng Parameter:

```
def user_params
  params.permit(:country)
end
```

{ "utf8"=>"✓", "country"=> "USA" }